# Proofs for UTXO set with Utreexo accumulator

Tags: algorithm, transactions, cryptography, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I am trying to understand the Utreexo technology and I've met a problem. In Utreexo we have a forest of trees where every tree has 2^k leaves. We have 3 operations:

```
add(acc, newNode) : Proof // simply adds new UTXO to our Utreexo, and returns the proof for added element.
verify(acc, proof) : Bool // gets the proof as argument and checks that the element is still in set.
remove(acc, proof) // removes element with given proof from accumulator.
```

The question is: I added a new UTXO and got the proof. After that, some changes happend (*different delitions and additions*) and the structer of the Utreexo has changed. Now, as I see, my proof (*that I received when I added the new UTXO*) will not be correct. How to deal with this problem? Or I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're understanding how Utreexo works correctly. The proofs generated for a single accumulator state is only valid for that state. A new proof must be generated if the accumulator was changed with additions and deletions.

For example, a proof for a single UTXO at block #500,000 will not be valid for block #500,001.

#### Further explanation:

In a general sense, Utreexo is a fancy [Merkle Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree). A "proof" is all the nodes needed to hash up to the root. For this tree:

```
 14                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 |---------------\                                                                                                                                                                                               
 12              13                                                                                                                                                                                              
 |-------\       |-------\                                                                                                                                                                                       
 08      09      10      11                                                                                                                                                                                      
 |---\   |---\   |---\   |---\                                                                                                                                                                                   
 00  01  02  03  04  05  06  07
```

A node is only required to keep the root, so that node's view of the tree may look like this where only the root, `14`, is kept.

```
 14                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 |---------------\                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 |-------\       |-------\                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 |---\   |---\   |---\   |---\
```

If someone wanted to proof the existence of node `00`, they will need to provide the following nodes: `00, 01, 09, 13`. These are node needed to be able to hash up to `14`, which then the verifier will check if the `14` they stored matches the one calculated with the proof of `00, 01, 09, 13`.

So for **this** tree, the proof generated will be nodes `00, 01, 09, 13`.

Let's say then the tree is modified with the removal of node `07`. The resulting tree will look like so:

```
  12                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  |-------\                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  08      09      10                                                                                                                                                                                              
  |---\   |---\   |---\                                                                                                                                                                                           
  00  01  02  03  04  05  06
```

If we want to prove `00` again, the nodes required are `00, 01, 09` and we will match it against `12`. This is different from the previous proof of `00, 01, 09, 13`.

In Bitcoin terms, since a modification to the accumulator happens when a new block is generated, the proof will change from block to block.